# How to show run tool only when there is an error in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, tdd

I use TDD quite a lot, and I was wondering if there is a way to show the Run Tool window only when there are failed tests?

Or to be more generic, for any run configuration, I would like the Run Tool window to be shown only when something goes wrong. Otherwise I would prefer the little non-obtrusive green pop-up to appear. Like when you run a lot of tests and you minimize the Run Tool by clicking on the "down arrow" in its top-right corner. When the tests are done, a little green pop-up appears over the minimized window.

I would also compromise for an answer that tells me how to keep the Run Tool always minimized, and only see little pop-ups, regardless if they are green or red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not exactly the answer you wanted but if you look in the RunConfiguration (Run->Edit Configurations -> JUnit) for your test run you should see a checkbox called 'Activate tool window'. If that box is ticked then the Run Tool window will pop open even if its minimised. When it's not ticked then the Run Tool window will stay minimised.

So, for any individual existing test run you can change the check box value to prevent the tool window appearing. If you're doing TDD that could mean you have many configurations for specific test cases / suites etc, which you would need to change individually.

In the longer term, you probably want to avoid future run configurations popping up the test. You can do that through the Defaults -> JUnit section in the RunConfigurations window.

Comment: Thank you @sisyphus This is almost perfect. I tried various solutions like the Tool Window plugin, but this is better. It keeps test results discreet, but when needed I can open the tool window with alt+4 or alt+5.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in the tab "Logs" you can check the option "Show console when a message is printed to standard error stream"

When this option is checked the window is opened automatically if some test fails.